# Div isn't wrapping content anymore when childrens float left

Tags: html, css, css-float

I created this jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem
https://jsfiddle.net/7spz9a57/4/
The two buttons are inside a div with the class `buttonholder`
the buttons are simple `<a>` tags with the class button.
i found out that when i add

```
.button {
...
float: left;
...
}
```

to my css the `buttonholder` div isn't wrapping the `<a>` tags anymore.
I really have no idea why.
I don't want to give `buttonholder` a fixed sice :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the `float`, as floated elements do not take up. You need to give the parent:

```
.parent {overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: Okay, why? Because? (Yes, I know; the OP clearly doesn't. And won't learn anything from this answer as currently written, except that `overflow: hidden` is magic that sometimes works.)